# header=FALSE not working when importing multiple CSVs at once

Tags: r

I am trying to import multiple CSVs from a folder at once, but the CSVs do not have column names. The following code works, but the first row is converted into column names:

```
dat <- list.files(pattern="*.csv") %>% lapply(read.csv)
```

When I try to use the code below:

```
dat <- list.files(pattern="*.csv") %>% lapply(read.csv(header = FALSE))
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : argument "file" is missing, with no default

Any idea how I can avoid this?

Comment: try `dat <- list.files(pattern="*.csv") %>% lapply(function(x) read.csv(x,header = F))`?

Answer (score 4):

The issue comes from incorrect specifying of additional parameters to `FUN`.

`? lapply`:

> `lapply(X, FUN, ...)`
>
> `...`       optional arguments to FUN.

You need to make a tiny change to your code to get it to work:

```
dat <- list.files(pattern="*.csv") %>% lapply(read.csv, header=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the tidyverse you might want

```
list.files(pattern=".csv") %>%
   purrr::map(readr::read_csv, col_names=FALSE)
```

(watch out for differences in default behaviour between `read.csv` and `readr::read_csv`)

Comment: downvote for gratuitous tidyverse? (I wouldn't have mentioned it except that OP was already using `%>%`)